# UITableView lag while scrolling even without any network operation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a very simple `tableview` with a prototype cell in my project. I have no network operation and the data in the tableview cell is populated using hard coded values. Still the tableview is not smooth while scrolling. I am not able to figure out what is causing this lag. Code for the `ViewController.swift` file is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //  MARK: Table view delegate and data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reviewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReviewTableViewCell
        //        cell!.label.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.reviewerNameLabel.text = "John Smith"
        cell.dateLabel.text = "12 months ago"
        cell.publisherNameLabel.text = "xyz publisher"
        cell.reviewTextLabel.text = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiop1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiop1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
        return cell
    }


}
```

I have set the tableview and prototype cell using the storyboard so for debugging simplicity, I have uploaded the project on github. You can get the complete project from [here](https://github.com/therohansanap/table-view-lag)

Comment: Why such a huge text??

Comment: doesnt lag for my iphone6, whats your device?

Comment: It a dummy prototype tableview. This same tableview I am going to add in my project to show list of reviews from various publishers. So to imitate the large reviews, I have put this large dummy text.

Comment: I am using simulator on Macbook @Tj3n

Comment: my iphone 5s also doesnt lag, maybe because u'r using simulator?

Comment: its normal for simulator to lag if u run many background things or use hdd or sth... its normal thing :/ try use real device and see

Comment: on the simulator I see the lag as well, is your storyboard alright? because i it I see the tableview width and height is set to 0.

Comment: I can see my tableview width set to 400 and height set to 600. The tableview row height is set to 160

Comment: Weird, your tableview then invisible for me lol, i cant see or do anything with it

Comment: Please take pull from github and if storyboard is set to `wAny hAny` then change is to `wCompact hAny` value in the bottom blue color bar. @Tj3n

Comment: Ah yes, i can see it now, and it look pretty normal and correct to me, i still dont see the lag as well

Comment: You don't see lag on simulator? @Tj3n

Comment: It's just not so fluently like in real device, but quickly scroll through and again 20 cell is fine, nothing different even after i change your long text to short or remove the imageview, all the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100538/discussion-between-the-rohan-sanap-and-tj3n).